# Qt Svg file on graphicsview

Tags: qt

How to load **SVG** file on **graphicsview**
using menubar signal (*.ui file*).
What code have to be written in `On_actionOpen_Triggered`?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `QGraphicsSvgItem`. Just specify the filename in the constructor.